# Prompting the user for correct input - tic tac toe game

Tags: python

I'm working on a program that simulates the tic-tac-toe game between two players. The program does what I want so far, except for the part where  I ask the players for input. I want the program to check whether the (3 x 3) grid already contains a mark (for example, 'X' or 'o'), and keep prompting the same player for a correct input before switching turns. Here is what I have so far:

```
board = [
        0, 1, 2,
        3, 4, 5,
        6, 7, 8
        ]

def main():
    print_instructions()
    start = str(input("Your game is about to begin. Press 'Q' if you want to quit, or 'K' to proceed: "))
    while start != "Q":
        get_input1()
        get_input2()


def display_board(board):
    print(board[0], "|" , board[1] , "|" , board[2])
    print("----------")
    print(board[3] , "|" , board[4] , "|" , board[5])
    print("----------")
    print(board[6] , "|" , board[7] , "|" , board[8])


def print_instructions():
    print("Please use the following cell numbers to make your move: ")
    display_board(board)


def get_input1():
    userInput = input("The first player marks with a 'X'. Type an integer between 0 up to 8 to indiciate where you want to move: ")
    userInput = int(userInput)
    if userInput < 0 or userInput > 8 or board[userInput] == "X" or board[userInput] == "o":
        print("Wrong input! You cannot move there! ")
    else:
        board[userInput] = "X"

    display_board(board)

def get_input2():
    userInput = input("Turn of second player. You mark with a 'o'. Where would you like to move? Type an integer between 0 and 8: ")
    userInput = int(userInput)
    if userInput < 0 or userInput > 8 or board[userInput] == "X" or board[userInput] == "o":
        print("Wrong input! You cannot move there! ")
    else:
        board[userInput] = "o"

    display_board(board)



main()
```

I still have to write the part where the program decides who the winner is, but I want to get the `def get_input` function right first. How can I check for a valid input in this case? I tried using a `while` loop, but that one just kept prompting the user indefinitely without terminating (maybe I did something wrong there). Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: See what happens when you change the `if` to `while`. You'll also have to get rid of the `else:` (and un-indent `board[userInput] = "X"`).

Comment: You should probably try to condense those two get_input functions into a single function that takes an argument to specify which player.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to take input in the while loop!
Try this.

```
while userInput < 0 or userInput > 8 or board[userInput] == "X" or board[userInput] == "o":
    print("Wrong input! You cannot move there! ")
    userInput = input("Please give a valid move.")
board[userInput] = "X"
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it partially. Now if I first type the wrong input, I get the the message "Please give a valid move", which is what I wanted. But then if I insert a different integer (a valid one), I get an error of the form "TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()"

Comment: Yeah, a simple fix is to use int(input(...))